# For next loop end once all status is true

Tags: lua

I am working on a script for a map of a game that I will be making. It is kind of like the chaser system in s4 league.

My problem is that once everybody has their "waschaser" set to true, the script should issue a  "close map" notice, but once everybody has been chaser, nothing happens and I cant figure out why.

Here is how my table is set up

```
chaserdb_players = { }
chaserdb_players[charname] = { score = 0, death = 0, kill = 0, waschaser = false }
```

Now once the map has started, it will search for the next available person with waschaser = false.

```
   for characterName,i in next, chaserdb_players do
     if (i.waschaser == false) then
      local player = getPlayerByName(characterName, map_copy)
      if (player ~= nil) then
        addChaserState(player)
        break
       end
      end
    end
```

in the addChaserState(player) function it switches the waschaser = true for that character.

What I am having issues with is that once everybody in the map has their waschaser = true, I need a system notice to start, which i have attempted by doing

```
for characterName,i in next, chaserdb_players do
          if (i.waschaser == false) then
            local player = getPlayerByName(characterName, map_copy)
            if (player ~= nil) then
                addChaserState(player)
                break
            end
        else
            Notice("All players have been chaser! The map will close in 30 seconds!")
            map_close = true
        end
    end
```

here is the getPlayerByName function

```
function getPlayerByName(name, map_copy)
BeginGetMapCopyPlayerCha(map_copy)
for i = 0 , chaserdb_playercount - 1 , 1 do
    local player = GetMapCopyNextPlayerCha ( map_copy )
    if (player == 0 or player == nil) then 
        return nil
    else
        local playerName = GetChaDefaultName(player)
        if (playerName == name) then
            return player
        end
    end
end
end
```

But that does not work.

Can anybody help? If you need more information feel free to let me know and I will add it.

Comment: Shouldn't `getPlayerByName(i, map_copy)` be `getPlayerByName(characterName, map_copy)`?

Comment: Or is `i` actually the character name, and `characterName` something else?

Comment: Nope, getPlayerByName(i, map_copy) is the correct one

Comment: ah i is the character name, sorry i poorly labelled it -i fixed it-

Comment: Your `getPlayerByName` function loops with `i`, yet does not use `i` anywhere else in the function...

Answer (score 1):

Move your notice outside the for loop. And use a boolean flag to check for any possible errors:

```
local bFlag = true
for i,characterName in next, chaserdb_players do
    if (characterName.waschaser == false) then
    local player = getPlayerByName(i, map_copy)
        if (player ~= nil) then
            addChaserState(player)
            break
        end
    else
        bFlag = false
    end
end
if bFlag then
    Notice("All players have been chaser! The map will close in 30 seconds!")
    map_close = true
end
```

Comment: This did not work either, it is still repeatedly looping through the table looking for the next one

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more idiomatically:

```
local allChased = true
for name, character in pairs(chaserdb_players) do
    if not character.waschaser then
        local player = getPlayerByName(name, map_copy)
        if player then
            addChaserState(player)
            break
        end
    else
        allChased = false
    end
end
if allChased then
    Notice("All players have been chaser! The map will close in 30 seconds!")
    map_close = true
end
```

Wrapping that in a function works well:

```
function nextChaser()
    for name, character in ipairs(chaserdb_players) do
        if not character.waschaser then
            local player = getPlayerByName(name, map_copy)
            if player then
                return player
            end
        end
    end
end

local player = nextChaser()
if player then
    addChaserState(player)
else
    Notice("All players have been chaser! The map will close in 30 seconds!")
    map_close = true
end
```

Comment: When I tried this, it would just send the notice to close even if they have not been chaser yet

Comment: See my comment on your question. It looks like you've named your variables confusingly. See my update, which should now work

Comment: Nope didn't work. I edited my topic. I added the getPlayerByName function